# How to run a java jar from Hadoop that needs some rapid miner jars

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, rapidminer

I am running this command from hadoop directory which includes  lib/ , project dependencies and everything it needs.

```
hadoop jar myjar.jar
```

My code runs a rapid miner process with hadoop mapper, its library jars is also includes in lib directory.

But it does not get rapidminer jars , except these hadoop get all the other jars.
I  am using rapidminer free version.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jar files in Hadoop needed for Main, Mapper, Reducer .
for Main u can put lib in your desired directory.
But mapper, reducer takes jar from 
`hadoop_home/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib`
So you should make sure your jar files should also be there.

Comment: You *can* put them there, that is not your only option, though. https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/hadoop-add-third-party-libraries-to-mapreduce-job/

Comment: what are the other options ??